# Allowing people to edit/proofcheck my posts on wordpress.com

Tags: blog, proofreading

I have a frequent issue of publishing posts on my blog that contain basic typos, which can be quite embarrassing for an otherwise well written post.

On Stack Exchange, other users have the privileges to make edits to posts, and this is quite often use to fix typos and formatting.

It would be quite nice if I could do this for my blog too. My blog is hosted on Wordpress.com.

My blog is usually published via Facebook, so it's my friends who read it first. What would be great is if I could give permission to certain friends to suggest edits to a post, which could then be approved by me.

Is this possible?

Otherwise - how else do I avoid allowing typos through, while at the same time maintaining a fast throughput of posts?

Comment: For $40 per post, I'll fix your spelling and grammar. For $60 per post, I'll rewrite it in terza rima.

Comment: You might find more help on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.  (Well, not your final question, which is pure writing and not tools, assuming you're already using some sort of spellcheck.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a WordPress site, you should be able to create various users who have different levels of permission. Give your two or three trusted friends their own usernames with Admin or Editor permissions, and those people should be able to log in and edit your posts.

Comment: In addition, you can save something as a 'draft,' and then allow them to post it once it is proofread. I believe you can even schedule the posts to post themselves at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also install the Grammerly browser plugin which will do spell-check for you in browser as you write, or write your posts in Word or similar editor and do spell-check / grammar editing prior to publishing live.